# Missing surface texture on rendering

Tags: rendering

I hope someone can help me. I have a project where i have to draw some simple urban environment. I have different types of objects and surfaces.
My Problem: The surface of the grass and vegetation isn't visible on the final render (see the pic). I can see it in the viewport, the render switch is on, the normals are ok.
Can someone help me to solve this problem, what have I forgot?
Thank you! :)
MT
[image: 1Camera-3Shading-1Problem]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved the problem myself. The surface mesh has particle system on it (the trees) and I've unchecked the "Show Emitter" function before. Checked it again and now it works like a charm! :)